# How can I deserialize JSON data to this class structure?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

So basically I want to deserialize JSON data from sepcific URL to this class structure and then use it to display it on a page.

I don't understand how should I deserialize it because there are two classes that are compatible with JSON structure on the url.

This is the code shown below.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Rootobject rootobject = new Rootobject();

        rootobject.regions[0] = _download_serialized_json_data<Region>("https://visservice.meteoalarm.org/api/v1/regions?language=ATOM");
    }


    private static Region _download_serialized_json_data<Region>(string url) where Region : new()
    {
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Region>(json_data) : new Region();
        }
    }


    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Region[] regions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Region
    {
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public float[][] bb { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Edit:

Value of json_data:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the value of `json_data `?

Comment: I see ATOM in your url. Look at [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication). There are classes for working with the ATOM format.

Comment: @vivek nuna I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your class definitoins, it should be  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json_data)`